# Shorthand return

Tags: go, shorthand

The following code generates a syntax error (**unexpected ++ at end of statement**) in Go 1.6 or 1.7:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var x int

func increment() int {
        return x++   // not allowed
}

func main() {
  fmt.Println( increment() )
}
```

Shouldn't this be permitted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an error, because the `++` and `--` in Go are statements, not expressions: [Spec: IncDec Statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#IncDec_statements) (and statements have no results that would be returned).

For reasoning, see Go FAQ: [Why are ++ and -- statements and not expressions? And why postfix, not prefix?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#inc_dec)

> Without pointer arithmetic, the convenience value of pre- and postfix increment operators drops. By removing them from the expression hierarchy altogether, expression syntax is simplified and the messy issues around order of evaluation of ++ and -- (consider f(i++) and p[i] = q[++i]) are eliminated as well. The simplification is significant. As for postfix vs. prefix, either would work fine but the postfix version is more traditional; insistence on prefix arose with the STL, a library for a language whose name contains, ironically, a postfix increment.

So the code you wrote can only be written as:

```
func increment() int {
    x++
    return x
}
```

And you have to call it without passing anything:

```
fmt.Println(increment())
```

Note that we would be tempted to still try to write it in one line using an assignment, e.g.:

```
func increment() int {
    return x += 1 // Compile-time error!
}
```

But this also doesn't work in Go, because the [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) is also a statement, and thus you get a compile-time error:

> syntax error: unexpected += at end of statement

Comment: Thank you @icza,  That was instructive.  Apologies for the massive delay in acknowledging your response.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution is right that the OP's code does not work because in go increment/decrement(x++/x--) statements are expressions that don't return a value.

However the solution presented has a slightly different effect than the original request.

x++ would return the value of x then increment in C like syntax.

however the opposite would happen if you do it this way:

```
x++
return x
```

You can negate that issue by reducing your initial value by one or by using a defer statement as written here:

```
func incr() int {
    defer func() { counter++ }()
    return counter
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/rOuAv7KFJQw

Comment: I upvoted this because I think this answer not only answers the OP question but it also answers how to do the same thing in go (fix it in the go away)  to get the same effect it would in a language that allows doing it as the OP intended