# Is ++ Allowed In Go Or Not?

Tags: function, go, operators

Consider this Go code (which can be easily executed [here](https://repl.it/@JimLynch/Go-Pass-By-Ref-Or-Pass-By-Val-Replit)):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

  // initialize an int variable
  i := 7
  fmt.Printf("%T\n", i) // prints "int"

        // runs a simple for loop
        for i := 1;  i<=5; i++ {
                fmt.Printf("Welcome %d times\n",i)
        }


  fmt.Println(oneLarger(i))

}

// passes arg by VALUE by default
func oneLarger(x int) int {
  return x++ // produces compile error
}
```

To me it is very interesting that when I execute this code it gives me the error, "./main.go:23:11: syntax error: unexpected ++ at end of statement".

When I comment out line 23 the comment runs fine; it doesn't complain at all about the i++ in the for loop. However, it doesn't like the x++ in my function. Why is this? What is the general rule for the ++ operator in Go?

Comment: It is allowed but you can't return it, unlike c/c++

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shorthand return in Go (golang)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280447/shorthand-return-in-go-golang)

Comment: That one is even covered in the FAQ https://golang.org/doc/faq#inc_dec . Contrary to other languages it is helpful in Go to read the Spec and the FAQ (once more) if a question comes up: It is all there in understandable form.

Comment: @Volker "contrary to other languages"... lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` [needs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#IncDec_statements) an expression:

```
ReturnStmt = "return" [ ExpressionList ] .
```

But `++` is an statement. So you cannot return 
`x++`.